# Providing popups in an asp.net web application that contain server controls

Tags: c#, web-development, web-applications, asp.net

What is the best way to provide popups that contain asp.net server controls? I am working on a  .net site. I have search functionality where if someone presses a button a panel appears where they can input the search information. I would like this to be a popup instead. Normal JavaScript won't work because the controls operate server side. So how do I go about creating a popup that is interacted with via server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PopUpControlExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx), which is part of the ASP.NET Ajax library. There's a modal popup version as well.